# Is there a way to dynamically choose which state I want to update in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, code-injection, setstate

For example if I have a bunch of `useState` hooks such as:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [age, setAge] = useState(0)
const [location, setLocation] = useState('')
```

and a function that takes a string value such as:

```
const handleClick = string => console.log(string)  // Name
```

Is there any way of dynamically choosing which state I update by passing the string value to the function call? Something along the lines of:

```
const handleClick = (string) => {
    console.log(string)  // Name
    set${string}('John Doe')
}
```

Comment: Seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Why do you want this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, even if you can dynamically execute code by `eval` or `Function`, it will not recognize the target `useState` because of the modulation system, you can work around it as suggested by the answers by using `object` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single object is usually used for this.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  location: ''
})

const handleClick = (key, value) => setState({...state, [key]: value});
```

You could also do something like this:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [age, setAge] = useState(0)
const [location, setLocation] = useState('')

const map = {
  name: setName,
  age: setAge,
  location: setLocation
}

const handleClick = (string) => {
    map[string]('John Doe')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this behaviour by grouping your states into one

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  location: '',
});

const handleClick = (key, value) => {
  setState((prev) => ({...prev, key: value}))    
}
```

Comment: Exactly my thoughts